# Only allow SSH incoming and outgoing

Tags: ssh, firewall, ssh-tunneling

I am trying to only allow `SSH` incoming and outgoings on my firewall, but the problem is that `FTP` can also be used even though I `DROP` at the end of the script

```
# Incoming SSH
$iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT

# Outgoing SSH
$iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
```

The way I `DROP` is by:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

The result of `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables=/usr/sbin/iptables

$iptables -F

$iptables -P INPUT
$iptables -P OUTPUT
$iptables -X

$iptables -F -t nat

$iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

$iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

$iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

$iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$iptables -A OUTPUT --p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: can you post the output of `iptables -L`?

Comment: Have done it, please check

Comment: with this config you basically accept everything in and out. You would have to flush the rules first. `iptables -F` flushes all the rules.

Comment: @blissini I do flush at the start

Comment: You mean when the system boots?

Comment: I meant at the start of the script

Comment: Would be better to see the whole script then.

Comment: Have uploaded it

Comment: `$iptables -P INPUT` and `$iptables -P OUTPUT` are not valid iptables commands. Should look like `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of each of your `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains accepts everything. You can remove them with these two commands

```
iptables -D INPUT 1
iptables -D OUTPUT 1
```

But be sure you will still have access (ideally physically at the console) before running them.

---

Now you've provided your script it's possible to suggest alternatives

```
#!/bin/bash -e
PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH

# Reset to a sane state, even if just temporarily
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Erase all the rules
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

# Simple NAT rule for outgoing traffic
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# Allow loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow the return half of established connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming and outgoing ssh
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# You probably want other stuff permitted here such as DNS on 53/udp and 53/tcp
# and maybe NTP on 123/udp
# iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

# Default policy is to discard all traffic
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Comment: what does these 2 lines do?

Comment: @Hudhud they will delete the first rules of the INPUT and OUTPUT chains, which are the ones accepting every connections

Comment: You mean I should replace them with the drops?

Comment: @Hudhud no, in the *iptable* you showed us there's already a "DROP all" rule, but it's being over ruled by an "ACCEPT all" rule at the beginning of the chain. If you delete those, the chain will only accept the connections that fit the remaining ACCEPT rules conditions. But as roaima said, be sure you have access to your machine to avoid locking yourself out..

Comment: How do I delete those rules?

Comment: I've tested it but it doesn't work. I've placed the 2 commands in the beginning of the script

Comment: @hudhud It's nothing to do with a script that you haven't shared with us. It's about deleting the rules that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @hudhud please consider deleting the comments that are no longer relevant

Comment: For some weird reason the incoming SSH doesn't work. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Hudhud I don't mind-read. What does "doesn't work" mean? What does the server's `auth.log` say? Does my answer exactly as given work as requested in your question?

Comment: It works again :) I was missing "iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT" What does this line do?

Comment: @Hudhud as the code comment says, it allows the return half of established [or related] connections. TCP/IP connections require traffic flow in both directions; this rule allows the return half through.